# Access Query - Too Complex to be evaluated, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I have an access database.  There is a field that is [Start Date].  The [Start Date] has values of 01/01/2017 and only one that is 07/24/2017.  The [Start Date] field is a Short Date field in the table.  When I change the 7/24/2017 to 01/01/2017 the query runs fine, however when I have July selected in the drop down and that form value is 7 and the 2017 in the Year drop down the following query says it is too complex to be evaluated.  I am trying to use the dateserial function to do a datediff and some division against a value with a decimal.  Here is the query:

```
Base Charge: Round(Sum(IIf(DateDiff("d",[Return to COE Regions].[Start Date] 
,CDate(DateSerial([Forms]![Main]![cboReportYear],[Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportMonth],1)))<30,[Base Charge HAL].[Base Charge]/DateDiff("d",
[Return to COE Regions].[Start Date],CDate(DateSerial([Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportYear],[Forms]![Main]![cboReportMonth],1))),[Base Charge HAL].[Base 
Charge])),2)
```

The dateserial typically is:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),1)
```

I am trying to put the form drop down values in as the date.  I have also tried this:

```
Base Charge: Round(Sum(IIf(DateDiff("d",[Return to COE Regions].[Start 
Date],format(DateSerial([Forms]![Main]![cboReportYear],[Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportMonth],1,"mm/dd/yy"))))<30,[Base Charge HAL].[Base Charge]/DateDiff("d",
[Return to COE Regions].[Start Date],format(DateSerial([Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportYear],[Forms]![Main]![cboReportMonth],1,"mm/dd/yy")))),[Base Charge HAL].[Base 
Charge])),2)
```

I have also tried:

```
Base Charge: Round(Sum(IIf(DateDiff("d",[Return to COE Regions].[Start 
Date],format([Forms]![Main]![cboReportMonth]/1/[Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportYear],"mm/dd/yy"))<30,[Base Charge HAL].[Base 
Charge]/DateDiff("d",
[Return to COE Regions].[Start Date],format(DateSerial([Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportMonth]/1/[Forms]![Main]![cboReportYear],"mm/dd/yy")),[Base 
Charge HAL].[Base 
Charge])),2)
```

I have also concatenated to try and string it together.  The July Value in the month drop down which is 7 won't calculate in that query.

From what I have read there is difficulty in queries with Form Drop Down Values.  Is there a work around?  Is it suggested that I store the values in a vba variable or run the query in vba instead?

Comment: I don't know whether this is the reason for the error, but I know it will cause an error:- in your "also tried" your `DateSerial([Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportYear],[Forms]![Main]![cboReportMonth],1` is missing its closing bracket, and `DateSerial([Forms]![Main]!
[cboReportMonth]/1/[Forms]![Main]![cboReportYear]` is missing its closing bracket as well as two parameters (it needs year, month and day passed to it - but you are passing one number calculated by two divisions, i.e. something like `8 / 1 / 2017` which is approx `0.003966`)

Comment: Also, why are you doing `CDate(DateSerial(...))`?  `DateSerial` is already a `Date` so there is no point trying to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Access don't know what the form expressions may hold, so specify that as parameters.

In SQL:

```
PARAMETERS
    [Forms]![Main]![cboReportYear] Short,
    [Forms]![Main]![cboReportMonth] Short;
SELECT ... <your query>
```

And do remove *CDate* from your expression as already noted.